# form is not getting updating after submitting like button

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When submitting the button after clicking like it is creating the object successufuly but like field is updating with null value and django is getting error 302. Can somebody please help me with this.

### After Edit

I have removed **form_valid** function from the **SongVoteUpdateView** now update part is working fine but if I removed **form_valid** function from **SongVoteCreatView** It is throwing intigrity error like this `NOT NULL constraint failed: album_vote.song_id`. [For trace back please refer this link](http://dpaste.com/0YXY6EE/duplicate/), if not removed it will creat blank object with no like.

### models.py

Codes in models.py

```
class VoteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(self,song,user):
        try:
            return Vote.objects.get(song=song,user=user)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Vote(song=song,user=user)

class Vote(models.Model):
    UP = 1
    DOWN = -1
    VALUE_CHOICE = ((UP, "️"),(DOWN, "️"),)


    like = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=VALUE_CHOICE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = VoteManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'song')
```

### views.py

Codes in views.py

```
class SongDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Song
    template_name = 'song/song_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
           vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(song=self.object, user = self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_url = reverse('music:song_vote_update', kwargs={'song_id':vote.song.id,'pk':vote.id}) #'pk':vote.id
            else:
                vote_url = reverse('music:song_vote_create', kwargs={'song_id':vote.song.id})

            vote_form = SongVoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_url'] = vote_url
        return ctx

class SongVoteCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    model = Vote

    def get_success_url(self,**kwargs):
        song_id = self.kwargs.get('song_id')
        return reverse('music:song_detail', kwargs={'pk':song_id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['song_id'])
        vote_obj, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj, user = user) 
        form.instance = vote_obj
        return super(SongVoteCreateView).form_valid(form)

class SongUpdateVoteView(UpdateView):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    model = Vote

    # def form_valid(self, form):
#     user = self.request.user
#     song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['song_id'])
#     vote_obj, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj, user = user) 
#     form.instance = vote_obj
#     print(form)
#     return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        song_id = self.kwargs.get('song_id')
        return reverse('music:song_detail', kwargs={'pk':song_id})
```

### urls.py

url mapping

```
    path('album/song/<int:pk>/',views.SongDetailView.as_view(), name='song_detail'),
    path('album/song/create/<int:song_id>/',views.SongVoteCreateView.as_view(), name='song_vote_create'),
    path('album/song/update/<int:song_id>/<int:pk>/', views.SongUpdateView.as_view(), name='song_vote_update')
```

### song_detail.html

Codes in html page

```
 <div>
     <form action="{{vote_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vote_form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Vote</button>
     </form>
 </div>
```

### forms.py

Code in forms.py

```
class SongVoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    like = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=Vote.VALUE_CHOICE)

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ['like',]
```

### error Code

response got in console.

```
[31/Oct/2019 04:15:19] "GET /album/song/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3560
**[31/Oct/2019 04:15:21] "POST /album/song/update/1/8/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0**
[31/Oct/2019 04:15:21] "GET /album/song/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3560
```

Comment: can you post your forms.py code ? you got a 302 redirect error seems like it involve the url. And if possible, print the code error instead of a request response code

Comment: @LinhNguyen I have added forms.py can you please look at it now

Answer (score 0):

I have explicitly mentioned like in the form_valid in SongVoteCreateView as shown below. Now the form is not creating blank object and redirecting to the correct page.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        like = form.cleaned_data.get('like')
        user = self.request.user
        song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['song_id'])
        vote_obj, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj, user = user, like=like) 
        form.instance = vote_obj
        return super().form_valid(form)
```